# How do you use usb debugging with eclipse and real android device

Tags: android, debugging

I'm trying to debug an android application using my Samsung Infuse 4g phone. Usb debugging is enabled on the phone. I've added in the manifest debuggable = true; Logcat says debugger has settled (1325). But when I run the code, it doesn't stop at my breakpoint and I don't see any variables in the variables window. Any ideas what's going wrong here? This is the logcat output:

```
04-03 00:55:47.210: I/System.out(8726): Sending WAIT chunk
04-03 00:55:47.218: I/dalvikvm(8726): Debugger is active
04-03 00:55:47.415: I/System.out(8726): Debugger has connected
04-03 00:55:47.415: I/System.out(8726): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-03 00:55:47.613: I/System.out(8726): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-03 00:55:47.819: I/System.out(8726): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-03 00:55:48.023: I/System.out(8726): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-03 00:55:48.234: I/System.out(8726): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-03 00:55:48.433: I/System.out(8726): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-03 00:55:48.636: I/System.out(8726): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-03 00:55:48.839: I/System.out(8726): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-03 00:55:49.042: I/System.out(8726): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-03 00:55:49.249: I/System.out(8726): debugger has settled (1325)
```

The only time I see that the debugger is doing something is when I purposefully crash the program. Then I see the exception for Double.ParseDouble(String) but I'm missing the source code for it... I've even tried the emulator and I get the same problem, no debugging till I crash the program.

```
package com.example.calculator;



public  class Math {
double mathValue;
double totalValue;
int lastOperator;

public double getTotalValue(){
    if (this.totalValue == 0)
        return this.mathValue;
    else
    return this.totalValue;
}

public void add(){

}

public void setOperater(String nextOperater){
    if (nextOperater == "+")
        this.lastOperator = 1;

    if (nextOperater == "-")
        this.lastOperator = 2;

    if (nextOperater == "*")
        this.lastOperator = 3;

    if (nextOperater == "/")
        this.lastOperator = 4;

    if (nextOperater == "")
        this.mathValue = 0;



}

public void doMath(double inValue){
    this.mathValue = inValue;
    switch (lastOperator){
    case 1 : Add();
            break;
    case 2 : Subtract();
            break;
    case 3 : Multiply();
            break;
    case 4: Divide();
            break;

    }

}

public void Add(){
    System.out.println("The line before my breakpoint");
    totalValue += mathValue; <---- break point
    System.out.println("The line after my breakpoint");
}

public void Subtract(){

    totalValue -= mathValue;
}

public void Multiply(){

    totalValue *= mathValue;
}

public void Divide(){
    if (mathValue == 0)
        totalValue = 0;
    else
        totalValue /= mathValue;

}

}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.calculator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.calculator.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: where in your code do you have your breakpoint? Could you show us that and the manifest while you're at it?

Comment: edited as requested, I added a console.out.println() to my code to make sure this line is being called and I do see in logcat my println

Comment: To be perfectly clear: you see "The line before my breakpoint" in your logcat? (It's not in reflected in your current logcat)

Comment: I just added that.... I found the problem. Somehow skip all breakpoints was selected in the controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure 'skip all breakpoints' is not enabled in debugging controls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the app in debug mode

[image: Debug Mode]

Comment: if I wan't running in debugging would I have logcat records showing the debugger has settled? And Debugger has connected?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your application as "debuggable" in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    ... >
    ...
</application>
```